# Add route to image in react

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, three.js, react-three-fiber

I am entering `localhost:3000/xf` manually, I want to click on img1.jpg to route the application to `/xf`, here is the component:

I tried few of these methods, but none worked:

```
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';

function Pages() {
  const { width } = useThree((state) => state.viewport)
  return (
    <>
      <Page position={[-width * 1, 0, 0]} urls={['/trip1.jpg', '/trip2.jpg', '/trip3.jpg']} />
      <Page position={[width * 0, 0, 0]}>
        <Link to="/xf">
          <Image position={[0, 0, 0]} scale={[width * 1 / 3 - 0.4 * 2, 5, 1]} url="/img1.jpg" />
        </Link>
        <Image position={[-width * 1 / 3, 0, -1]} scale={[width * 1 / 3 - 0.4 * 2, 5, 1]} url="/img2.jpg" />
        <Image position={[width * 1 / 3, 0, 1]} scale={[width * 1 / 3 - 0.4 * 2, 5, 1]} url="/img3.jpg" />
      </Page>
      <Page position={[width * 1, 0, 0]} urls={['/img4.jpg', '/img5.jpg', '/img6.jpg']} />
      <Page position={[width * 2, 0, 0]} urls={['/trip1.jpg', '/trip2.jpg', '/trip3.jpg']} />
      <Page position={[width * 3, 0, 0]} urls={['/img1.jpg', '/img2.jpg', '/img3.jpg']} />
      <Page position={[width * 4, 0, 0]} urls={['/img4.jpg', '/img5.jpg', '/img6.jpg']} />
    </>
  )
}
```

```
import * as THREE from 'three'
import { Suspense, useRef } from 'react'
import { Canvas, useFrame, useThree } from '@react-three/fiber'
import { Preload, Image as ImageImpl } from '@react-three/drei'
import { ScrollControls, Scroll, useScroll } from './ScrollControls.tsx';
import { BrowserRouter, Routes, Route, Link } from "react-router-dom";
import MJ from "./components/MJ";
import './App.css';

function Image(props) {
  const ref = useRef()
  const group = useRef()
  const data = useScroll()
  useFrame((state, delta) => {
    group.current.position.z = THREE.MathUtils.damp(group.current.position.z, Math.max(0, data.delta * 50), 4, delta)
    ref.current.material.grayscale = THREE.MathUtils.damp(ref.current.material.grayscale, Math.max(0, 1 - data.delta * 1000), 4, delta)
  })
  return (
    <group ref={group}>
      <ImageImpl ref={ref} {...props} />
    </group>
  )
}

function Page({ m = 0.4, urls, ...props }) {
  const { width } = useThree((state) => state.viewport)
  const w = width < 10 ? 1.5 / 3 : 1 / 3
  return (
    <group {...props}>
      <Image position={[-width * w, 0, -1]} scale={[width * w - m * 2, 5, 1]} url={urls[0]} />
      <Image position={[0, 0, 0]} scale={[width * w - m * 2, 5, 1]} url={urls[1]} />
      <Image position={[width * w, 0, 1]} scale={[width * w - m * 2, 5, 1]} url={urls[2]} />
    </group>
  )
}

function Pages() {
  const { width } = useThree((state) => state.viewport)
  return (
    <>
      <Page position={[-width * 1, 0, 0]} urls={['/trip1.jpg', '/trip2.jpg', '/trip3.jpg']} /> /
      <Page position={[width * 0, 0, 0]} urls={['/img1.jpg', '/img2.jpg', '/img3.jpg']} />
      <Page position={[width * 1, 0, 0]} urls={['/img4.jpg', '/img5.jpg', '/img6.jpg']} />
      <Page position={[width * 2, 0, 0]} urls={['/trip1.jpg', '/trip2.jpg', '/trip3.jpg']} />
      <Page position={[width * 3, 0, 0]} urls={['/img1.jpg', '/img2.jpg', '/img3.jpg']} />
      <Page position={[width * 4, 0, 0]} urls={['/img4.jpg', '/img5.jpg', '/img6.jpg']} />
    </>
  )
}

export default function App() {
  return (
    <>
      <BrowserRouter>
        <Routes>
          <Route path="/xf" element={<MJ />} />
          <Route path="/" element={
            <Canvas gl={{ antialias: false }} dpr={[1, 1.5]}>
              <Suspense fallback={null}>
                <ScrollControls infinite horizontal damping={4} pages={4} distance={1}>
                  <Scroll>
                    <Pages />
                  </Scroll>
                  <Scroll html>
                    <h1 className='font' style={{ position: 'absolute', top: '20vh', left: '25vw' }}>generative</h1>
                    <h1 className='font' style={{ position: 'absolute', p: '20vh', left: '125vw' }}>adversarial </h1>
                    <h1 className='font' style={{ position: 'absolute', top: '20vh', left: '225vw' }}>networks</h1>
                  </Scroll>
                </ScrollControls>
                <Preload />
              </Suspense>
            </Canvas>
          } />
        </Routes>
      </BrowserRouter>
    </>
  )
}
```

The problem is I am unable to add route, link or any other method inside three